# How to rotate a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

It's quite frustrating not to be able to do such a simple task:  I have an "app" with a single viewcontroller, and in  it a single UIImageView, that's initialized to a specific image at potrtait mode.

Now when the iPhone gets roteated to landscape mode and the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation event fires, at which I return YES, my resulting UIImageView looks totally screwed up: either the image is stretched so to fill landscape mode frame (which looks ridiculuous of course) or the top and bottom of the image are cropped.

How can I have my UIImageview and the contained image handle the device rotation gracefully, and display normal looking image at landscape mode as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image view's parent `UIView` [`autoresizesSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to `YES`.

Also set the `autoresizingMask` of the image view to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

Comment: Thanks and indeed the image is no longer staretched.

Comment: But it is not the full image either

Answer (score 0):

you also want to look into your UIImageView's contentMode. aspectFill and aspectFit behave very differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can always subclass UIView and override the `layoutSubviews` method to manually lay out your subviews. The transition to landscape will still be animated, and you can do whatever you want with the subviews.

Comment: BTW, you'll need to set the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`